# iPhone Application Queries

Tags: iphone, ios

Is there any way to achieve the following things via my application's code on the iPhone:

1. API for locking/unlocking the ios 5.0 device
2. Wipe the  device data as in below app
   http://www.engadget.com/2010/06/18/apple-launches-find-my-iphone-app/
3. Language change of the device
4. Device sound change etc

Answer (score 1):

All of the activities you list here are handled by private methods, and as such, are off limits to App Store developers (and there is no official API to access them). That said, anything is possible if you're willing to forego distribution in the App Store and able to dig into the undocumented features of the native and/or jail broken OS.